# NHibernate 3 LINQ provider creates non-ansi join syntax

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm pretty new to LINQ (and NHibernate's LINQ provider)

I have a query that joins 3 tables in a grandparent-parent-child using many-to-one mappings.

The actual SQL NHibernate is throwing out is using old-school FROM table1, table2, table3 join syntax.

Is there a way to make it use ANSI joins instead? (I see that using Fetch() will do this, but the syntax isn't exactly standard LINQ stuff)

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

Keep in mind that, while the ANSI syntax is cleaner and allows for easier outer joins, it's semantically equivalent to the "old one" for inner joins, so you shouldn't care.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately the people I need to convince to move from EF and all it's nice VS integration to NH do think it's important to produce "good sql". :(

Comment: If "good SQL" just means ANSI joins to them, it's a losing battle.